# DataStax Enterprise 4.5 on RHEL / CentOS 7 won't fully install cqlsh

Tags: datastax-enterprise, cqlsh

When trying to install DataStax Enterprise from the yum repository, cqlsh won't actually install because it depends on python 2.6 while RHEL/CentOS now ships with python 2.7 and removed 2.6.

It seems it should also be able to accept python 2.7, as far as I know, it is compatible. I just used the CentOS 7 system python 2.7 to install pip and then pip install cqlsh and it all seems to be good.

Answer (score 0):

Hm... yes, that's tricky. The target path for site files is in the package, so one would need different packages for different versions of python (I believe). I filed a ticket, we will look into this.

Comment: Thanks! The repositories are really nice to have. Appreciate the work.